# Redux form pre populated data

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am using a redux form, on load of the component I am getting values for my text fields from an api response, when I have these values populated and submitted as I have not touched the fields - i am seeing validation errors - like they are empty - how to pass these existing values to props?

```
const emailValfromapi = this.props.data && this.props.data.email ? this.props.data.email : [];
    const { handleSubmit, fields: { email, abc, def, etc } } = this.props;
            <fieldset className="form-group">
                          <div className="input-wrapper">
                            <input value={emailValfromapi} id="email" {...email} type="email" className={email.touched && email.error ? 'error-red' : ''} required />
                            <label className="input-label" htmlFor="Email">To</label>
                            { email.touched && email.error && <div className="alert-danger"> { email.error } </div> }
                          </div>
                        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3):

In `redux-form` you do not pass in the values for inputs yourself, but instead use [the `Field` component](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/Field.md/) to wrap inputs and let the library handle the data bindings. In this case the input is populated, but `redux-form` has no knowledge of its existence, because it's not wrapped in a `Field` component. This example gives you a good rundown on the basic use of the `Field` component.

Additionally, to pass initial values to the form component, you need to use the `initialValues` prop (best described by [this example](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializeFromState/)).

Hope this helps!